# MAX31865 SPI communication failed

Tags: c, linux, spi

I have a problem with communication with MAX31865. I wrote a simple linux application but when I run it the program never end. I don't have any response from MAX31865.

here is my code (only to conf):

```
static void transfer(int fd)
{
    int ret;
    uint8_t tx[] ={0x80};

    uint8_t rx[ARRAY_SIZE(tx)];
    struct spi_ioc_transfer tr = {
        .tx_buf = (unsigned long)tx,
        .rx_buf = (unsigned long)rx,
        .len = ARRAY_SIZE(tx),
        .delay_usecs = delay,
        .speed_hz = 0,
        .bits_per_word = 0,
    };

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(1), &tr);
    if (ret == 1)
        pabort("can't send spi message");

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ret = 0;
    int fd;

    parse_opts(argc, argv);

    fd = open(device, O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0)
        pabort("can't open device");

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MODE, &mode);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't set spi mode");

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_MODE, &mode);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't get spi mode");

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_BITS_PER_WORD, &bits);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't set bits per word");

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_BITS_PER_WORD, &bits);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't get bits per word");
    printf("%d",bits);

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MAX_SPEED_HZ, &speed);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't set max speed hz");

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_MAX_SPEED_HZ, &speed);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't get max speed hz");

    printf("spi mode: %d\n", mode);
    printf("bits per word: %d\n", bits);

    transfer(fd);
    printf("max speed: %d Hz\n", speed);

    transfer(fd);

    close(fd);

    return ret;
}
```

I will be grateful for any help

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: 1) indent consistently.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  un-indent before every closing brace '}'.  never use tabs for indenting.  Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts.

Comment: You have a problem interfacing with external hardware.  YOU have all you need to  fix it.  We have a bit of source code and 'program never end. I don't have any response'.  You did not even tell us how far the program got when you stepped through it with your debugger.  We don't even know if you have power on the chip.  We cannot help you, and you should have known that before you posted:(

Comment: Insert some `printf`for debug so that you know exactly which call that stalls

Comment: this is an excerpt from the man page for `ioctl()` *Usually, on success zero is returned.  A few ioctl() requests  use  the
       return  value  as an output parameter and return a nonnegative value on
       success.  On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.*  Amongst other things it says that, on success, a zero is not necessarily returned.   When returning from `main()` and wishing to indicate success, a 0 must be returned.  Therefore, `ret` might not contain 0, so should not be used in a `return` operator.

Comment: everything is ok until ioctl() function. I have checked the mosi on the osciloscope and everything is OK but the program can't continue

Comment: when posting a question that has the form: `this code does not work` you must post a minimal code that cleanly compiles and still shows the problem.  Also post the actual input, the expected output and the expected output.  Use a debugger to determine the point in the code where it fails.  include the `#include` statements.  etc etc.

Comment: which `ioctl()` function call is failing?  Post info that we can use, not some generic statement.  like: `the ioctl()` function failed.`  the question mentions `MAX31865` but fails to indicate what that is, nor where we can get the spec sheet.  Are you expecting us to read your mind, or just guess?

Comment: Do not edit the existing text of a question, rather when editing, post additional text.  Otherwise, prior comments become meaningless and/or misleading

Comment: someone help?  I've add full code in the additional post

Answer (score 0):

Here is my full code. I've note where is the problem

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/spi/spidev.h>


static void pabort(const char *s)
{
    perror(s);
    abort();
}

static const char *device = "/dev/spidev0.0";
static uint8_t mode = 3;
static uint8_t bits = 8;
static uint32_t speed = 1000000;
static uint16_t delay;

#define ARRAY_SIZE(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof((a)[0]))


static void transfer(int fd)
{
    int ret;
    uint8_t tx[] ={0x80};

    uint8_t rx[1];
    struct spi_ioc_transfer tr = {
        .tx_buf = (unsigned long)tx,
        .rx_buf = (unsigned long)rx,
        .len = ARRAY_SIZE(tx),
        .delay_usecs = delay,
        .speed_hz = 0,
        .bits_per_word = 0,
    };

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(1), &tr); //->> this ioctl function makes problems
    if (ret == 1)
         pabort("can't send spi message");

 }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ret = 0;
    int fd;

    fd = open(device, O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0)
        pabort("can't open device");

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MODE, &mode);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't set spi mode");

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_MODE, &mode);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't get spi mode");

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_BITS_PER_WORD, &bits);
    if (ret == -1)
    pabort("can't set bits per word");

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_BITS_PER_WORD, &bits);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't get bits per word");
    printf("%d",bits);

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MAX_SPEED_HZ, &speed);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't set max speed hz");

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_MAX_SPEED_HZ, &speed);
    if (ret == -1)
        pabort("can't get max speed hz");

    printf("spi mode: %d\n", mode);
    printf("bits per word: %d\n", bits);  //---> This printf works fine

    transfer(fd);   
    printf("max speed: %d Hz\n", speed);  //--> This printf doesn't work

    close(fd);
}
```

Comment: Why read  in the speed, bits etc. if you are not going to use them in the IO request struct?

Comment: It's test program. I want to test how it works. It isn't  necessary. The problem is in transfer() function